# SignalR Core Check if users are connected

Tags: asp.net-core-signalr

I know that in the old SignalR days that this wasn't possible so you were forced to keep a list of clients that were connected even though it obviously existed.

I'm hoping there is a way to pass an array of user ids (that signalR should be able to match from the authentication claims of users) and have it tell me which ones are online and which are not. The reason why is that we want to send an email if they're not online to receive notifications.

So easy question: Is there a way to get the users that are currently connected?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there's nothing built in for this

Comment: Wow.  Can't believe how long this has been a major issue with signalr that requires major additional resources to work around with no real solution from Ms...

Comment: Yes, there's an entire unexplored feature area here. I'd expect us to dig into it again once all of the basics are covered.

Comment: @davidfowl any change as of 2021?